# Jenkins throws "Executable not found in $PATH"

Tags: jenkins, skaffold

I have installed kompose in my Jenkins machine through CLI and it is successfully installed.

I am trying to build a job which uses this "kompose" executable but it fails with "Exectable not found in the $PATH" error.

**Error:**

```
    + skaffold init --compose-file docker-compose.yaml
    time="2019-11-13T10:39:00Z" level=fatal msg="running kompose: exec: \"kompose\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Please let me know if I need to make anymore changes to communicate the executable to Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

On your Jenkins job has executed, you can review its environment variables (on the left side of the job execution instance page)

Check the `PATH` value and see if it includes where you have installed `kompose`.

Check also which user is actually running Jenkins: its `$PATH` might differ from your current local user.